# CSS Code for different color for various links on my wordpress blog

Tags: css, wordpress

I am about to create a new blog but before launching it I want to test all the functionality for it. So I am not good with either CSS or any other coding. I want to know how can I show the internal links of my blogs in Green color, the links going out to some other sites (external links) in Red color and Affiliate links to Amazon or Ebay in Blue color on my all blog posts.

Please, can anyone tell me how to do it on my upcoming wordpress blog?

Comment: please add your code please

Comment: I would suggest it is best to handle this explicitly with CSS classes. Add a CSS class, lets say `external`, to external links and then style it with, say, `a.external{color:blue;}`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a css attribute selector … something like this:

```
// All green
a {
    color: green;
}

// External red
a[href*="//"] {
    color: red;
}

// Amazon and ebay blue
a[href*="amazon.com"], a[href*="ebay.com"] {
    color: blue;
}
```

You can select like this:

- `[attribute=value]`: exact value
- `[attribute*=value]`: value somewhere
- `[attribute^=value]`: value at start
- `[attribute$=value]`: value at end

With this you can select the links based on the href attribute they have and style them as you wish … you get the point i think?

A good solution for checking link on a specific page is [Integrity for Mac](https://peacockmedia.software/mac/integrity/free.html) Thats a app that lists all links of a page.

Comment: Better to make external the default style, that way you don't have to make a list of all external sites and other TLD issues like amazon.co.uk. Also you have small error where you have copied the "starts with attribute" for the "ends with attribute" (`[attribute$=value]`)

Comment: Yeah it depends a bit on the link structure … i am guessing that internals are relative so with a[href*="//"] i overwrite for externals … thanks for pointing that error out ;)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your linking convention you "could" make some assumption and use [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

The following is based on the assumption that internal links are not absolute. E.g `<a href="/somepath/to/somepage">` and external paths are absolute (which they have to be), e.g `<a href="https://www.google.com">`

```css
/*Default style, applied to internal links*/
a {color:red;}
/*href contains // therefore absolute, and therefore external*/
a[href*='//'] {color:blue;}
/*href starts with #, therefore a link to an element on the page*/
a[href^="#"] {color:black;}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google - External</a>
<a href="//apple.com">Apple - External</a>
<a href="/some/internal/link">Intneral</a>
<a href="#internaPage">Links to internal page Id</a>
```

**HOWEVER**

I would probably make this explicit and use classes instead. No assumptions made and you have control

```css
/*Default style, applied to internal links*/
a {color:red;}
/*class for external links*/
a.external {color:blue;}
/*class for links to page id*/
a.idLink {color:black;}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="external">Google - External</a>
<a href="//apple.com" class="external">Apple - External</a>
<a href="/some/internal/link">Intneral</a>
<a href="#internaPage" class="idLink">Links to internal page Id</a>
```